# Push Services in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hi friends I am developing an application to display push notification.I would Like to know weather it is Chargeable Push Notification Essential.

Answer (score 2):

RIM charges based on the frequency and size of the push data, and the number of clients being pushed to. When you apply for push credetials the limitations and cost of each type of account are explained. Current information is available from the [Push Service site](https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/).

Comment: I would like to know weather essential push notification is free? And the difference between essential and push notification

Comment: The push program I'm using (which pre-dates the current plans) is free. I suggest you contact RIM if you don't find the information you need is not on that site. They are quite responsive to developer needs now.